# SQL query for checking whether a column with a specific value has its correspondent row with another specific value in the same column

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I am not completely sure how to solve this problem.

My data looks like this:

```
ENT   ACC L_TYPE K_TYPE
0100  123 660    S
0100  123 673    S
```

And I would like to see whether L_TYPE 673 has no correct correspondent with L_TYPE = 660.

I want to find out whether the column L_TYPE with the value 673 has also its correspondent 660.
All the other values do not change.

However, I would need the SQL as general as possible.

The only thing that I was capable of writing was this. So, I was able to find out that at least many rows with different values are in L_TYPE.

```
SELECT ENT, ACC, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
WHERE K_TYPE = 'S'
GROUP BY ENT, ACC
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

I thought about using a cursor but I am not quite sure whether this solves my problem.

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this problem?
I use DB2 as a database.

Comment: Please share your desired output

Comment: The desired output will be:

ENT   ACC L_TYPE K_TYPE
0100  123 660    S
0100  123 673    S

I would like to find out whether every L_TYPE with 673 has its correspondent L_TYPE with 660.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rows for which every  `ENT, ACC` combination there are L_TYPE of both 600 and 673.

```
SELECT ENT, ACC, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
WHERE K_TYPE = 'S' and l_type in (660,673)
GROUP BY ENT, ACC
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Comment: If there are single row with 600 then it should not be appeared in result set.

Comment: I was too fast and deleted my last statement. I think I am too tired.

Answer (score 0):

For all rows that are type 673, look for a row with matching keys and where the type is 660.

To find where a 673 does not have a corresponding 660:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM TABLE T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 
ON T2.ENT=T1.ENT 
    AND T2.ACC=T1.ACC 
    AND T2.K_TYPE = T1.K_TYPE 
    AND T2.L_TYPE = 660
WHERE T1.K_TYPE = 'S' 
AND T1.L_TYPE = 673 
AND T2.L_TYPE IS NULL
```

To find where a 673 has a corresponding 660:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM TABLE T1
JOIN TABLE T2 
ON T2.ENT=T1.ENT 
   AND T2.ACC=T1.ACC 
   AND T2.K_TYPE = T1.K_TYPE 
   AND T2.L_TYPE = 660
WHERE T1.K_TYPE = 'S' 
AND T1.L_TYPE = 673
```